# apport-autoreport.service loaded failed failed Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled

Tags: 22.04, lightdm, systemd, gdm, apport

```
OS              Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel          5.15.0-52-generic
DE: GNOME 42.5 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11300H (8) @
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile
Memory: 3173MiB / 15795MiB
```

I am not getting this error when I open my terminal:
[image]

I followed this recommendation and reboot my system, but it is still the same message.

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

After that, I got a prompt that made me choose between lightdm and gdm3, and I chose gdm3 did not allow me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The message:

apport-autoreport.service loaded ***failed* *failed*** Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled

is probably unrelated to the package **lightdm**.
The message can be confirmed by running:

```
$ sudo systemctl --failed
```

[using "sudo systemctl --failed" to confirm apport-autoreport.service failure message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqP2v.png)

Recent upgrades/updates on Ubuntu seem to trigger this **apport-autoreport.service** error. The apport automatic crash report uploading, called **whoopsie**, becomes disconnected tfrom the local system's /var/crash store of reports, and dies, reporting nothing to Canonical.

Here is a solution:

```
$ # Do we have the problem?
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled whoopsie.path
disabled
$
$ # Yes, let's enable whoopsie.path
$ sudo systemctl enable whoopsie.path
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/whoopsie.path → /lib/systemd/system/whoopsie.path.
$ 
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled whoopsie.path
enabled
$ 
$ # Now start the service and check if failure is cleared.
$ sudo systemctl start apport-autoreport
$ sudo systemctl --failed
  UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
0 loaded units listed.
$ # Problem: solved!!! Reboot and "systemctl --failed" to double-check
```

Details:
The whoopsie.path is a systemd stanza that tells whoopsie package, which uploads things from /var/crash to Canonical for reporting, that /var/crash is the directory that should be checked (and monitored) for crash reports, which itself is directed via apport-autoreport.path .

Note: The apport mechanism had previously been [a security problem](https://securitylab.github.com/research/ubuntu-whoopsie-daisy-overview/).

To see the apport crash reports ***your system*** has submitted to **[errors.ubuntu.com](https://errors.ubuntu.com/)**, do the following:

```
$ # Grab system's unique ID and form URL to look at logs
$ echo https://errors.ubuntu.com/user/$(sudo cat /var/lib/whoopsie/whoopsie-id)
https://errors.ubuntu.com/user/(128_character_hex_id_here)
$ # and open the URL generated
```